# List all calendar events on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

How can I see the list of all my events on my iPhone 4s? Not just the ones for that day or by searching with an alphabet letter.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a bit tricky on iOS. If you are in Calender view, there are three icons on the right side. The third from the right is the list icon. But there are two types of that list icon: one only shows three lines, the other shows two lines and a square.

The mode you are talking about must be the one with the two lines and the square. So you see the calender view on top ("the square") and a list of events for that ("the two lines").

Press this button so it is not selected any longer. Now you see the calender view without the list. Now press the "Today" button in the lower left corner. The view will switch to show you the timeline of the day, and also the third icon from the right switched to the one with the three lines. Pressing this "three lines" button will show up the event list you are searching for.

Comment: How is this answer substantially different from the answer already provided?  If just a few details need to change, don't add a new answer just edit and update the answer already there.

Comment: my feeling was that the first answer didn't get the point at all. Hitting the today button several time did not help anything, it's important to see the difference between the two modes of the button, as described in my answer.

Comment: despite 6 years of iOS updates, this still works on iOS 15.7 as of Oct/2022

Answer (score 0):

I agree this is non obvious and takes a few try

Click on the menu icon so it is not highlighted (the third from left in the top row)

Then keep hitting today at the bottom left hand corner until the calendar disappears.

You then have a list of events

Comment: That did not work on my 4s.  The calendar never disappeared just the date highlighted and blinked. I did not get the list of all the events I put in.

Comment: I see no menu icon on my calendar page.

Comment: I hate icons as you can't tell people about them - it is the 3rd one from the right

Comment: The only items above the calendar is  from Left to right: date then the list icon then the magnifying glass icon then the + sign.  The List Icon just puts up the list for that day and hitting today when it is highlighted does nothing.  I might go by a apple store and see what they say.  Hour away so rather find a way to see all of them listed by asking someone who knows how to do it on my phone.

Comment: I mean the list icon as I said icons are not easy to read

Answer (score 0):

Completely non-intuitive, and it works differently on iPad vs iPhone.

On iPhone, from any view, click on the magnifying glass. Type in a '?'. This will show all events on all your calendars in an agenda format.

On iPad, select the magnifying glass. iPad by default will list all events in an agenda view, flowing under the Search box. The '?' trick still works, but there really is no need for it.